# Custom Users when using Jenkins Google Login Plugin

Tags: security, jenkins, devops

I am attempting to our company's Jenkins from the Jenkins user database + matrix based security to using Google Login Plugin and Role based strategy plugin to give us better control of our user accounts.

With this new set up I am wondering how I could go about creating a designated user which is used by scripts which trigger Jenkins jobs remotely. I would like to do this without having to add a user to our company's GSuite account as this costs a few $ per month. Before the switch to Google Login I could just create a user manually in the Jenkins user database and take the API token from there but since switching to Google Login there is no option to add a user (which makes sense given than the users are managed by Google now). At the moment it seems like I have to choose from:

- Use the old approach and forget about authenticating through google. This is not a great result as we want to minimize the number of user accounts we have to set up for new people joining the company to overhead of onboarding.
- Use Google Login Plugin and create a new dedicated "Jenkins" user in GSuite for these scripting / requirements. This costs money.
- Use an existing users API Token to avoid the cost of a new Google User in our GSuite account. This seems like bad practice which I'll regret at some point.

Is there a workaround which doesn't require a designated GSuite user or repurposing an existing Google users credentials just for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar research a while ago and it seems like there is no way to do so right now.

However, I'm using [SAML plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SAML+Plugin) with GSuite instead of Google Login Plugin, but from Jenkins security perspective I assume they work in the same way.

When you're using such plugin, Jenkins creates a `securityRealm` in its config. In my case it is:

```
  <securityRealm class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.saml.SamlSecurityRealm" plugin="saml@1.0.7">
```

Therefore, to have SAML and Jenkins security matrix work simultaneously, you have to have several security realms.

Here is a [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15063), which describes this issue, but it's still open

Regards!

Comment: I came accross that same ticket whilst researching my problem. Given that it's clearly an acknowledged and outstanding issue I have taken the approach of using a designated GSuite user for automated tasks. As it happens we already have one set up as we needed the credentials for some other applications a while back, so this turned out to be the simplest solution and also didn't add any cost in this instance.
Edit: And thanks for the reply - it at least confirms my understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking at how to trigger builds remotely when using the Google Login Plugin.
I ended up using the "Build Token Root Plugin" which solved this problem, without any need to create a dedicated user for this.

This plugin offers an alternate URI pattern which is not subject to the usual overall or job read permissions. Just issue an Http GET or POST to buildByToken/build?job=NAME&token=SECRET. This URI is accessible to anonymous users regardless of security setup, so you only need the right token.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin